# Configuration export via drush randomly change the value of labels\other content in multilanguage sites

Tags: 8, drush, i18n-l10n, configuration

I've a multilanguage site, with Italian set as default and English as secondary language.

When exporting the configuration via drush - `drush cex` command - sometimes the labels of other kind of content is exported, but the only actual difference is the change of language.

This happens often with a lot of views.

For example, for `views.view.who_s_online.yml` the difference is:

```
 @@ -41,7 +41,7 @@ display:
          submit_button: Apply
          reset_button: false
          reset_button_label: Reset
        - exposed_sorts_label: 'Sort by'
        + exposed_sorts_label: 'Ordina per'
          expose_sort_order: true
          sort_asc_label: Asc
          sort_desc_label: Desc
```

But there are other settings, for the "en" translation that sometimes differs only for the translation.

E.g. for `en\field.field.node.article.body.yml` the difference is:

```
 @@ -1,0 +1,0 @@
 - label: Abstract
 + label: Body
```

This is frustating because I often have to check a lot of files with no real difference. For some is actually dangerous as e.g. `en\addtoany.settings.yml` keeps to lose its settings during the export.

When this happens I've tried both to commit the exported files with just the language differences, or to discard them and to import the configuration (`drush cim`).

Neither of the solution are working long-term, as the problem appears again after a bit.

I've checked for possible issues on the drupal issue queue but found nothing. Any help?

Comment: Can it be that you switched the language in your user profile before the export?

Comment: @leymannx could you elaborate more your statement? Do you mean in the browser? I mean, if the last page loaded is in "en" language, then drush will export in english? In the opposite case, in italian?

Comment: I mean your Drupal user account. There you can switch the language in which the interface is being displayed. Did you switched the language there?

Comment: @leymannx No, the admin language has always been  'IT'. Btw the "Detection and selection" of the language order (from top to bottom) is: Selected language -> URL -> User -> Browser. Could be that somewhat related?

Comment: `admin language has always been 'IT'` – That's what I meant. You changed the admin language. What happens when you change it to EN (and flush caches)? Does the problem persist? (Nonetheless I somehow consider this a bug.)

Comment: @leymannx sorry I totally missed the notification. Yes, I tried to change the admin language but the problem occasionally appears too. Maybe somewhat more rarely but it still does that.

Comment: Yeah difficult. It would be so good if we'd know the exact steps to reproduce this issue starting from a Vanilla Drupal. Then this probably makes this a bug report, or at least a feature request to have an option passed to Drush maybe to pass the current language you want to have the config exported in.

Comment: Yes this is a good idea, as soon as I'll have a bit of extra time I could try to set up a vanilla and replicate the settings of the D9 site with problems, to see if I could replicate what is causing the problem.
Otherwise I find difficult to create a precise bug report - but the feature for drush would be certainly a good thing.